# How to - use regex in Nexus to search for this | or that?

Tags: cisco, cisco-nx-os, cisco-nexus-7k

So aggravating - i can't find good documentation on how to use the Nexus regex command.

So, if my interfaces look like this:

```
interface Vlan224
  description MANAGEMENT
  no shutdown
  ip flow monitor netflow-monitor input  
  no ip redirects
  ip address 10.214.224.2/24
  ip ospf passive-interface
  ip router ospf 1 area 0.0.0.3
  ip pim sparse-mode
  hsrp version 2
  hsrp 224 
  preempt 
  priority 120
  ip 10.214.224.1
```

I want to run something similar to:

```
show run | inc (interface Vlan)|(ip address)
```

And the output to look similar to (if this were on IOS):

```
interface Vlan10
ip address 10.1.10.1 255.255.255.0
interface Vlan 11
ip address 10.1.11.1 255.255.255.0
etc.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do a `show run | egrep interface.Vlan|ip.address`. It does grab a bit more info, but should provide similar output to what you see in IOS. I think grep might work as well, but I used egrep and got the correct output.

Comment: This works.  So, egrep has taken place of show X | inc ?  And the code looks for "interface"anything"Vlan" OR "ip"anything"address" ? (without the quotes)

Comment: I believe so. You can access the documentation for egrep on the 7k here: http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/switches/datacenter/sw/6_x/nx-os/fundamentals/configuration/guide/b_Cisco_Nexus_7000_Series_NX-OS_Fundamentals_Configuration_Guide_Release_6.x_chapter_0100.html#con_1225277

Answer (score 5):

If you are just looking for the IP addresses of the Vlan interfaces, a better way may be: `show ip int br | grep -i vlan`

Note: `show ip int br` in NXOS only shows layer 3 interfaces. To see status of all interfaces use `show int br`

UPDATE:

for NXOS 4.0(2) and earlier:
`show run | grep -i face\ vlan|ip\ address`

4.0(3) and up:
`show run | grep ignore-case face\ vlan|ip\ address`

also the `\` is how to escape the space with regex. Link for the NXOS regex: http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/switches/datacenter/sw/4_0/nx-os/fundamentals/configuration/guide2/fun_3about_cli.html#wp1237003

Comment: I also want to have info on the subnet information, so that's why I was trying to pull it out of the "show run".

Comment: I see. Then try this one on for size: `show run | grep -i face\ vlan|ip\ address`

this will also show all lines in the output that contain either "face vlan" or "ip address"

Comment: Richard, thanks, but get a carrot under the f after grep -i

Comment: should have looked deeper, my apologies. That syntax should work on NXOS 4.0(2) and earlier. For 4.0(3) and up replace `-i` with `ignore_case` here's the link http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/switches/datacenter/sw/4_0/nx-os/fundamentals/configuration/guide2/fun_3about_cli.html#wp1237003

Comment: Richard S, so it sounds like what I used to be able to do in ios with a | inc, I now need to do in NXOS with a | grep ignore-case blah blah blah.  And spaces need to be escaped, like this "\ " without quotes? and I can still use multiple |'s to use as logical or's?

Comment: three things: 1) in IOS only way to do an ignore case would be this: `| in [Vv][Ll][Aa][Nn]`, so not directly the same; 2) in IOS you didn't have to escape the space, but you could without issue; 3) i venture to guess that you can use multiple or's `|`

Answer (score 5):

An alternate syntax involving single quotes.

```
# show run | inc 'interface Vlan|ip address'
```

In NX-OS, argument parsing works a lot like bash.

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/switches/datacenter/sw/4_1/nx-os/fundamentals/configuration/guide/Cisco_Nexus_7000_Series_NX-OS_Fundamentals_Configuration_Guide__Release_4.1_chapter4.html#con_1225277) I have seen says this should work:

```
show run | inc interface_Vlan|ip_address
```

Although it does not seem to for me on a 4k blade switch.  I had success with

```
sh run | inc interface.Vlan|ip.address
```

Comment: That doesn't work on a 7K.

7K# sh run | inc interface_Vlan|ip_address
7K# sh run | inc interface_Vlan | ip_address - puts a carrot under the p.

No output at all.

Comment: I don't have Nexus to try it on but you might try (interface.Vlan|ip.address).   The ^ under the p sounds like it's interpreting the  "|i" as a second pipe.

Comment: @Pseudocyber: *caret :-)

Comment: Per docs, and unlike IOS, "the underscore is only treated as a regular expression for BPG related commands"

Answer (score 0):

The easy answer is that, for a one-to-one mapping from IOS to NX-OS, it looks like this:

**IOS**: `show run | inc (interface Vlan)|(ip address)` 
**NX-OS**:  `show run | inc 'interface Vlan|ip address'`

Note that this makes more sense when you leave out the extra parens in the original:

`show run | inc (interface Vlan|ip address)`

The key in this example is that for NX-OS, the parens are replaced by quote marks.

You could also use double quotes, i.e. `""`  .

NX-OS is Linux-based[[1]](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/switches/nexus-7000-series-switches/white_paper_c11-622511.html), and uses a *nix-like regular expression engine. The commands are odd comprises between English wording and standard regex idioms.

For example, what would be `egrep -v` in bash would look like `egrep ignore-case`
On the command line this would look something like

`show run | egrep ignore-case vpc`
 *or*

`show run | inc ignore-case vpc`

An example of the verbosity (and strength) of the new regex features:
`show run | egrep ignore-case  vpc  | egrep invert-match ignore-case peer`

This would be equivalent to a bash-shell `egrep -i vpc <input> | egrep -vi peer`

Nevertheless, there is considerably more power and flexibility here than in current IOS.

The basic Cisco documentation is [here](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus5500/sw/fundamentals/7x/b_5500_Fund_Config_7x/b_5500_Fund_Config_7x_chapter_0101.html#con_1237003)*, but your command-line `?` feature gives you quick reminders:

```
5k# show run | ?
  cut      Print selected parts of lines.
  diff     Show difference between current and previous invocation (creates temp files: remove them
           with 'diff-clean' command and dont use it on commands with big outputs, like 'show 
           tech'!) 
  egrep    Egrep - print lines matching a pattern
  grep     Grep - print lines matching a pattern
  head     Display first lines
  human    Output in human format
  last     Display last lines
  less     Filter for paging
  no-more  Turn-off pagination for command output
  section  Show lines that include the pattern as well as the subsequent lines that are more
           indented than matching line 
  sort     Stream Sorter
  tr       Translate, squeeze, and/or delete characters
  uniq     Discard all but one of successive identical lines
  vsh      The shell that understands cli command
  wc       Count words, lines, characters
  xml      Output in xml format (according to .xsd definitions)
  begin    Begin with the line that matches
  count    Count number of lines
  end      End with the line that matches
  exclude  Exclude lines that match
  include  Include lines that match

5k# show run | inc ?
  WORD         Search for the expression
  ignore-case  Ignore case difference when comparing strings
  line-exp     Print only lines where the match is a whole line

5k# show run | egrep ?
  WORD          Search for the expression
  count         Print a total count of matching lines only
  ignore-case   Ignore case difference when comparing strings
  invert-match  Print only lines that contain no matches for <expr>
  line-exp      Print only lines where the match is a whole line
  line-number   Print each match preceded by its line number
  next          Print <num> lines of context after every matching line
  prev          Print <num> lines of context before every matching line
  word-exp      Print only lines where the match is a complete word
```

- *Note* that the docs may be version and platform dependent.
  Here is the top-level for the Nexus 7K:
  [Cisco Nexus 7000 Series Switches Configuration Guides](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/switches/nexus-7000-series-switches/products-installation-and-configuration-guides-list.html)
  For the 5K:
  [Cisco Nexus 5000 Series Switches Configuration Guides](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/switches/nexus-5000-series-switches/products-installation-and-configuration-guides-list.html)

You'll then want to search "fun" (what else?) to find the *Fundamentals Configuration Guide* (which contains the Regular Expression section in the *Understanding the Command-Line Interface* chapter).

Easter egg? Chapter numbers are in binary for this doc.

If you walk through the docs, you'll find a lot more *nix-like command-line tools, including `cut`, `tr`, and on the 7K, `sed` and some other goodies.

Also, don't overlook the `prev` and `next` modifiers for 'include' matches.

This will grab lines containing foo, as well as three lines before and two lines after for context:
`show run | inc foo prev 3 next 2`